# If I have a breaking news and I am the first to publish the story how can I ensure Google indexes it fast and ranks it top

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, keywords, google-news

If I have a breaking news and assume that I am the first person to know. How can I get top place in google search?

Answer (score 5):

Google will crawl pages that have high PR and frequently change their content with much greater frequency then typical pages. StackOverflow pages seems to be crawled almost constantly as questions appear in Google's search very quickly after being asked.

So, to ensure you get spotted first, you will need to have a well established site that has accumulated a lot of quality links and updates regularly. You clearly aren't anywhere near that yet. So you may publish the content first but others who are slower then you, but crawled more frequently, will get listed ahead of you and earn links before your page is even crawled. Those links will give them a huge advantage (not to mention their internal linking will give those pages an added advantage as sites that large and established can spread the love around their site quite effectively (e.g. Wikipedia)).

Getting a top place in search isn't a quick and easy process. It takes time, effort, and some more time. If you don't even have a domain yet I'd say you're nowhere near where you need to be to get high rankings for "breaking news" type of content. **So get started!** You can't get there is you sitting on the sidelines.

Comment: Awesome explanation!!!! What if I have the phrase of the breaking news as my domain name. Here there are few scenarios like 1) The keywords in breaking news have no popularity at all (Never searched on google) 2) The keyword in breaking news have less popularity. You can say competition is just with 2-3 website on the first page. Please explain me and guide me....

Comment: If no one is searching for it, does it matter if you're ranked #1? Especially if the competition can be counted on one hand. You'll always be on the first page anyway. At that point just make sure your page title is very descriptive and catchy so they click on *your* link instead of theirs. Over time you'll get the links you need to start ranking ahead of them. If the competition is as small as you say, that shouldn't take too long. - Having the phrase in your domain name is always a good thing. But can your domain name actually be the name *every* breaking news? Or just the subject matter?

Answer (score 2):

> What if I have the phrase of the
>   breaking news as my domain name.

While there are entire sites ("[microsites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsite)") that are dedicated to a very narrow topic, they are far and few in between, and usually they're used as a marketing tool to supplement a main site with a broader topic. The reason is that it's just not worthwhile to create, market, and maintain a site for such a narrow scope of information/purpose. It's hard to generate significant quantities of quality content on a single news story, and without content, it's hard to bring visitors to your site or gain PageRank. If you have another well-established larger site, you can pass PR juice onto the microsite, but otherwise it's going to take a lot of time and effort to drive traffic to the site.

As John Conde noted, it takes time to build up the trust and authority of a site/domain. So is it a worthwhile investment to do so for a site that only covers a specific news story (a topic that likely has a very short shelf-life)? By the time you're able to build up the trust/PR of the site, the news story will likely be stale and few would be searching for the news story anyway.

Most search engines use algorithms specifically designed to filter out spammy throwaway sites that are quickly thrown up for a quick turnaround. That's why new sites are sandboxed by Google for the first few months. Instead, search engines favor well established sites that have been around for a long time, have a lot of original content, and are well maintained/frequently updated. So building a new site just to get top rank on a breaking news story just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -2):

Although it is very diffult to pull a news up in less time especially if is ralted to less popular keywords. But you can make it more popular. I suppose following steps may help you.

1. First write complete article over your site with copyright notes. Better if you register this article for copyright
2. Write another article with different title on some famous article directory, which is linking to your site.
3. Now the time is to advertise your news. So submit it to various social networking and bookmarking site.
4. Strat searching your own article on search engine using different keywords after some time of publishing

*dont forget to submit sitemap immediately after writing the article/news.